# How to have 2 Types with the same model in Graphene?

Tags: python, graphene-django

I created a model Checkout on my project, with a CheckoutType to handle the requests, but now i need a Profile, that is basically just getting many of the fields on Checkout. The problem is that Checkout and Profile will be retrieved by users with very different permissions, and the while the first one will have the right ones, the second one must not have them. so i went with creating 2 types:

Checkout:

```
class CheckoutType(ModelType):
    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        interfaces = [graphene.relay.Node]
        connection_class = CountableConnection
        permissions = ['app.view_checkout']
        filter_fields = {        
            'zone': ['exact'],
            'vehicle__mark': ['exact'],
            'status': ['exact']
        }
```

Profile:

```
class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields = ['zone','status']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        # The query context can be found in self.request.
        return super(ProfileFilter, self).qs.filter(salesman=self.request.user)

class ProfileType(ModelType):
    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        interfaces = [graphene.relay.Node]
        connection_class = CountableConnection
        filterset_class = ProfileFilter
```

The thing here is that, the first one shouldn't filter, and just be a regular schema, while the second one should filter by the user that made the request, that and the permissions is the reason i use 2, but as soon as i implemented, all the tests i did for the Checkout Type started to fail, since it seems it tries to use the ProfileType. I searched a little, and it seems that relay only allows a type per model in Django, so this approach doesn't seems possible, but i'm not sure how to overwrite the CheckoutType on another schema, or how to make a second Type with different permissions and different filters. Does someone knows if this is possible?

Comment: The question title should clarify this is not for vanilla `graphene`, but specifically for the `graphene-django` package that extends it and that it relates to django models.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is on the same boat, i think i found a way to make it work, but with a different approach, i just modified the CheckoutType a little:

```
class CheckoutType(ModelType):
    # Meta

    @classmethod
    def get_queryset(cls, queryset, info):
        if info.context.user.has_perm('app.view_checkout'):
            return queryset
        return queryset.filter(salesman=info.context.user)
```

Basically here i remove the permission from the Meta, since i don't want to check that there, and then i overwrite the get_queryset() to check if the user has the perms, if that's the case, then just return the normal query, but if not just filter(And any additional thing you want to do for people without the permission). I'm not sure if there's a better way, but definitely did the job.